# Show a specific view after backgrounded

Tags: objective-c

I would like to show a userID/password view after the app is backgrounded for security purposes.

How should I implement it? Should I be using `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the security reasons but as I tested in both
`- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application` and
`- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application`
None of these can show UIComponent during application is have been resigned. May be local notification can help you with this but these too wouldn't be able to do exactly what you want.